# What is the best way to calculate the time consumed of "copying a binary file in c++ on linux"?

Tags: c++, linux

I use the following code to copy a file with the size about  1.1 GB

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
 int read_fd;
 int write_fd;
 struct stat stat_buf;
 off_t offset = 0;

 /* Open the input file. */
 read_fd = open ("source", O_RDONLY);
 /* Stat the input file to obtain its size. */
 fstat (read_fd, &stat_buf);
 /* Open the output file for writing, with the same permissions as the
   source file. */
 write_fd = open ("destination", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, stat_buf.st_mode);
 /* Blast the bytes from one file to the other. */
 sendfile (write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
 /* Close up. */
 close (read_fd);
 close (write_fd);
  end = clock();

    cout << "CLOCKS_PER_SEC " << CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";
    cout << "CPU-TIME START " << start << "\n";
    cout << "CPU-TIME END " << end << "\n";
    cout << "CPU-TIME END - START " <<  end - start << "\n";
    cout << "TIME(SEC) " << static_cast<double>(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
   CLOCKS_PER_SEC 1000000 
CPU-TIME START 0 CPU-TIME END 6140000
 CPU-TIME END - START 6140000 TIME(SEC) 6.14
```

But, when I actually calculate the time, it(copying) takes time about 84 SEC!!! 
Now i will use  "structure  timeval" in the following code and  Output is: `83 456677` that it is almost the same with actual time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>  // sendfile
#include <fcntl.h>         // open
#include <unistd.h>        // close
#include <sys/stat.h>      // fstat
#include <sys/types.h>     // fstat
#include <ctime>
extern "C" {
 #include <sys/time.h>
 }
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   struct timeval diff, startTV, endTV;

gettimeofday(&startTV, NULL); 

    int source = open("source", O_RDONLY, 0);
    int dest = open("distination", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT /*| O_TRUNC/*/, 0644);

    // struct required, rationale: function stat() exists also
    struct stat stat_source;
    fstat(source, &stat_source);

    sendfile(dest, source, 0, stat_source.st_size);

    close(source);
    close(dest);

  gettimeofday(&endTV, NULL); 

timersub(&endTV, &startTV, &diff);

printf("**time taken = %ld %ld\n", diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

Then i will use 'pv source> destination'a command then Output is: `1.02e+03MB 0:01:24 [12.1MB/s] [===========================>] 100%` and it is the same with actual time.

And also when I copy the file in the mode graphical ( a copy/paste ordinary) it takes a time about 84 SEC.

**Questions**

1. What is the time calculated in  the first manner?
2. Does 'pv' or Pipe Viewer, correctly shows 'the time consumed for copying a file' by OS?
3. Do conclude we that the time consumed for copying by sendfile() is almost the same with OS?

Comment: Many participants on this site view/read questions by tag.  I changed your C++ tag to C.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe He's using `iostream` and `ctime` headers... This is  C++ code even though most of what he's doing is C.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Mea culpa, thanks. I re-added the c++ tag. OP when you say calculated the time you mean you looked at your watch right?

Comment: @SchighSchagh he is **including** `iostream`, not using it. And `ctime` is just `time.h`. The rest of the code is just C, has nothing to do with C++. SO **this is C, in C++**

Comment: For another POV: Run the program a couple times back-to-back to different files and subtract the destination files` create time-stamps.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the time calculated in the first manner?

It's the time your program spent using the CPU. clock() measures CPU time. Copying a file
typically spends most time doing other stuff (I/O,e.g. waiting for the harddrive to move or respond, waiting for locks in the kernel, and so on.).

> Does 'pv' or Pipe Viewer, correctly shows 'the time consumed for copying a file' by OS?

It shows the elapsed time it took from it received the first byte until it received the last byte.

Keep in mind that writing to a file normally just writes to the file system cache, so it's just writing to RAM. The OS flushes that cache to the drive at its leisure, which may be after your program, the `cp` program, or any GUI filemanager you used says the copying is done. (This is no real problem unless you cut the power, reading from the file you copied to goes through the same cache).

If you want to ensure data is flushed to the drive, call [fdatasync](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/fdatasync.html)() on the file descriptor.

This also means you can easily measure wildly different times for copying a file. If the file, or parts of it happens to reside in the file system cache, you're reading from RAM. If it is not in the cache, it needs to be read from the drive, which can be an order or two magnitude slower.

> Do conclude we that the time consumed for copying by sendfile() is almost the same with OS?

Sorry, I don't know what you are asking here..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it means that, can conclude we that the time consumed to copy a binary file by sendfile() equal to  the time consumed (to copy) by 'cp'?

Comment: @Code I don't know what you measured. If your 2. code example shows the same time as `cp`, then surly yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you may find [`strace -T`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) quite useful, unless you absolutely need to store stats inside your program.

The test

```
$  cat /dev/urandom > chunk.bin
^C
$  strace -T cp -p chunk.bin dust.bin
```

Outputs (see numbers in triangular brackets after each syscall)

```
stat("dust.bin", 0x7fff747c5640)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000303>
stat("chunk.bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=19202048, ...}) = 0 <0.000341>
stat("dust.bin", 0x7fff747c5290)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000281>
open("chunk.bin", O_RDONLY)             = 3 <0.000272>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=19202048, ...}) = 0 <0.000272>
open("dust.bin", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4 <0.000404>
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 <0.000272>
read(3, "\216\330A\27J\373\1a\10\262&\221B\255\271\227\342:\252?\334\3169a\212\27\205=+\300\273\370"..., 32768) = 32768 <0.000684>
write(4, "\216\330A\27J\373\1a\10\262&\221B\255\271\227\342:\252?\334\3169a\212\27\205=+\300\273\370"..., 32768) = 32768 <0.000359>
read(3, "\327\344\343|\243\247\211\200\211\212\331\247WF\324\33\276\317\241[{\24\354D\223\215\332\247\34\376\246W"..., 32768) = 32768 <0.000494>
write(4, "\327\344\343|\243\247\211\200\211\212\331\247WF\324\33\276\317\241[{\24\354D\223\215\332\247\34\376\246W"..., 32768) = 32768 <0.000379>
...
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0 <0.000226>
utimensat(4, NULL, {{1392157379, 551638340}, {1392157405, 783308564}}, 0) = 0 <0.000254>
fgetxattr(3, "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7fff747c4f50, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available) <0.000234>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=19202048, ...}) = 0 <0.000223>
fsetxattr(4, "system.posix_acl_access", "\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x04\x00\x06\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff \x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff", 28, 0) = 0 <0.000285>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.000250>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000267>
```